# Wordpress - print Custom Field with HTML content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to import HTML into wordpress WYSIWYG custom fields and later display it correctly.

The values get written by the importer, but when I try to  edit such a content type, the WYSIWYG editor is spammed with html-tags.

I tried different variants to escape the htmlspecialchars. With no succes. The WYSIWYG editor also displays those, instead of formatting the text.

Also, when i do `print_custom_field` in my template, the html does not get rendered, but displayed again. Obviously not what I would want.

All related content types are created with custom content type manager

https://code.google.com/p/wordpress-custom-content-type-manager/

My Question:

- Is it a bad idea in general to import html-snippets from a (trusted) external source?
- How can I trick the output from worpdress into rendering html for certain fields, instead of displaying it.

Comment: When you paste the HTML into the WYSIWYG editor, are you on the 'Visual' or "Text' tab? You should paste code into the 'Text' tab.

Comment: It's an importer plugin. The content does not have to be editable through wordpress. It gets automatically imported every night from a webservice. I just mentioned the Editor, because it also seems to have trouble dealing with htmlspecialchars encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually related to the view layer. Since that was not my business, I didn't care at first.

Turns out, that one has to us `htmlspecialchars_decode` in the templates, because the wordpress-api does `htmlspecialchars` on import.

The following code works fine

```
<? print htmlspecialchars_decode(get_custom_field('foo'));?>
```